# Spanner retries doesn't work after migration from 6.38.2 to 6.45

Tags: java, google-api, google-cloud-spanner

After migrating java-spanner lib from version 6.38.2 to 6.45.0 (gax migrated from 2.24 to 2.32) I have observed that retries on DEADLINE_EXCEEDED exception doesn't work.

I have custom retry configuration:

```
SpannerStubSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = builder.getSpannerStubSettingsBuilder();
settingsBuilder.readSettings()
            .setRetryableCodes({StatusCode.Code.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, StatusCode.Code.UNAVAILABLE})
            .setRetrySettings(
                RetrySettings.newBuilder()
                    .setInitialRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(10))
                    .setMaxRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(200))
                    .setRetryDelayMultiplier(1.5)
                    .setInitialRpcTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                    .setMaxRpcTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                    .setRpcTimeoutMultiplier(1.5)
                    .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
                    .build());
```

Having that and version 6.45.0 of the java-spanner lib many requests are ending up with exception DEADLINE_EXCEEDED after 0.0999s, so after initial RPC timeout, no retries after it. Before retries were applied and requests ended up with success.

How can it be explained? I've checked changes in the lib repository (both java-spanner and gax) but couldn't match anything for this specific behavior.

Comment: The example in your question sets the timeout- and retry settings for the `Read` RPC. This RPC is normally not used by the client library, it will normally use `StreamingRead`. Can you give an example of the part of your code that succeeded in 6.38.2 and fails in 6.45.0?

Comment: I have configuration for bot `Read` and `StreamingRead` both are the same

Comment: Regarding the example, I will try to do it, but it could be after the weekend

Comment: It seems that the issue happens only when the session needs to be created. First version that has this behavior is gax 2.28.1. Before that init-rpc-timeout is not taken into account, no retries but result is provided (if got in the total timeout limit)

Comment: @kpater87, please post your answer so that it would be helpful to other community members with similar question.

Comment: @RobertG I haven't put the answer before because it was rather observation than the solution. We fixed the issue by upgrading libs, details in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the issue by upgrading `spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies` to version 3.7.1, it contains:

```
com.google.cloud:google-cloud-spanner:jar:6.49.0:compile
com.google.api:gax:jar:2.34.1:compile
```

Version 3.7.0 of `spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies` was still affected by the issue, it contains:

```
com.google.cloud:google-cloud-spanner:jar:6.47.0:compile
com.google.api:gax:jar:2.33.0:compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as per comment of @kpater87:

> It seems that the issue happens only when the session needs to be created. First version that has this behavior is gax 2.28.1. Before that init-rpc-timeout is not taken into account, no retries but result is provided (if got in the total timeout limit).

You may check this link on [Google API Extensions for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs) for reference.